# ui-router populating templateurl and controllers nested abstract states with nested views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, nested-views

I have been experimenting with `ui-router` and I ran into a bit of a quirk.  I am unable to populate a view underneath an abstract state.  It appears that while the state is active, the view is not found

Here is an example :

the state provider :

```
$stateProvider
.state('search', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '',
    views: {
        '@': { 
            templateUrl: 'app/views/layout.html',
        },
        'full-page@search': {
            templateUrl : 'app/views/search/search.html',
        }
    }
})

//------------------------------------------------------------
// Search list view
//------------------------------------------------------------
.state('search.list', {
    url: '/search/users',
    views: {
        'content-container@search' : {
            templateUrl : 'app/views/search/user.list.html',
            controller  : 'SearchResults',
        }
    }
})

//------------------------------------------------------------
// Search view of one users's details
//------------------------------------------------------------
.state('search.user', {
    abstract : true,
    url: '/search/usr/{userId}',
    views: {
        'content-container@search' : {
            templateUrl: 'app/views/user/user.detail.html',
            controller : 'UserController', 
        },
    }
})

//------------------------------------------------------------
// View of the user's details
//------------------------------------------------------------
.state('search.user.view', {
    url : '',
    views: {
        'left-column@search' : { 
            templateUrl : 'app/views/user/user.detail.view.html',
            controller  : 'UserEditController',
        }
    }
})`
```

HTML:

index.html :

`<div>
   <div ui-view></div>
</div>`

layout.html :

`<div>
   <div ui-view='full-page'></div>
</div>`

search.html :

`<div>
   <div ui-view='content-container'></div>
</div>`

user.list.html :

`<div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="user in users">
            <a ui-sref='search.user.view({userId : user.userId})'></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>`

user.detail.html :

`<div>
    <div ng-view="left-column"></div>
    <div ng-view='right-column'></div>

</div>`

user.detail.view.html :

`<div> User information </div>`

I page state flow that I am trying to get is :

1) initial site loading of search.list (which bubbles up to

- 1.a: load `layout.html` into the default ui-view in *index.html* via the '@' view'
- 1.b: `search.html` is loaded via the "full-page" view in layout.html, then
- 1.c: `user.list.html` is loaded via the `content-container@search`  view in the search.list state. This is working fine and dandy

2) clicking on the list created in `user.list.html` loads search.user.view which should? bubble back to search.user,

- 2.a load *user.detail.html* in the `content-container@search` view of search.html, then (this works)
- 2.b load in *user.detail.view.html* in the `ui-view='left-column'` div of user.detail.html. (this does not work, "left-column" view is left empty.)

I originally thought this code performs the same pattern of abstract state ui-view population twice (once for the user.list, the other for user.detail.view) however, it appears this is not the case.  It seems as though the `"left-column"` view is searched before the content-container is populated

I'm new to the ui-router so I may have a misconception of the sequence of how abstract states populate or the intended use of abstract states.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there - here is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/U2QvUQpzRYA0rU5r41Cr?p=preview). The changes I made

#### user.detail.html

not the *ng-view* but **`ui-view`**

```
<div> 
   //<div ng-view="left-column"></div> 
   //<div ng-view='right-column'></div>
   <div ui-view="left-column"></div> 
   <div ui-view='right-column'></div>
</div>
```

#### state 'search.user.view'

the part after **`@`** delimiter must be the name of a *state* holding that ui-view - which is not *search* but **`search.user`**. As I show on `right-column` below - if this is in fact parent... we can skip it *(will be done for us behind the scene)*

```
.state('search.user.view', {
    url : '',
    views: {
        // 'left-column@search' : { 
        'left-column@search.user' : { 
           ...
        },
        'right-column@' : { 
           ...
        }
    }
```

Check the working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/U2QvUQpzRYA0rU5r41Cr?p=preview)